# How to find a green's function?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

everyone,I don't know how to solve the following question
$$\Delta u=\delta(x-x_{0})\delta(y-y_{0})\delta(z-z_{0})$$
where
$$u=u(x,y,z)$$
and satisfy the following conditions 
$$u|_{z=0}=0$$
$$u_{z}|_{z=h}=0$$
I'm not good at pde.Please give me a detailed answer.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I assume $0<z_0<h$. If $z_0\notin[0,h]$, then $u=0$ does the job.

Let $\gamma_0(x,y,z)=\frac1{4\pi\sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2)}$ denote the Green's function for the Laplacian $\Delta=-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}$ on $\mathbb R^3$. Then $\gamma_0(x-x_0,y-y_0,z-z_0)$ is a Green's function for the Laplacian, that is, it solves $\Delta u=\delta(x-x_0)\delta(y-y_0)\delta(z-z_0)$, but not with the boundary conditions you want.

To get the boundary conditions right, consider instead the sum
$$f(x,y,z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\gamma_0(x-x_0,y-y_0,z-z_0-2nh)
-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\gamma_0(x-x_0,y-y_0,z+z_0-2nh)\;.$$
If this was an absolutely convergent sum, you could check that it still satsifies the differential equations and satisfies the boundary conditions.

Unfortunately, both sums behave roughly as harmonic sums, so they diverge.
But you can arrange them so that the Leipniz criterion is satisfied, and get convergence by writing it as a sum of 
$$\gamma_0(x-x_0,y-y_0,z-z_0)-\gamma_0(x-x_0,y-y_0,z+z_0-2h)
+\gamma_0(x-x_0,y-y_0,z-z_0-2h)\mp\dots$$
and
$$-\gamma_0(x-x_0,y-y_0,z+z_0)+\gamma_0(x-x_0,y-y_0,z-z_0+2h)-\gamma_0(x-x_0,y-y_0,z+z_0+2h)\pm\dots$$

To see that this function is harmonic in $\mathbb R^2\times[0,h]\setminus\{(x_0,y_0,z_0)\}$, check that it has the mean value property because all summands have. Leaving away the very first summand gives a function that is harmonic on the whole stripe, so $\Delta u=\Delta\gamma_0(\cdot-x_0,\cdot-y_0,\cdot-z_0)$.